# WordPress - show most read posts in 7 days, query by filter

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, posts

I have wordpress plugin and there I have this query and filter:

```
<?php
  function filter_where($where = '') {
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
  }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
?>

<?php query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&ignore_sticky_posts=1&posts_per_page='. $numposts ); ?>
```

I need to get posts that are most read in 7 days, but this query only shows posts last 7 days, and when I do not type any post in lasts 7 days, plugin will show no posts = I must write posts...
But I want to make that will show always most read posts in 7 days...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the plugin  [WP Plugin: Top 10 posts and Views per post](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2005/11/25/wp-plugin-top-10-posts-and-views-per-post/) download this plugin and edit `top10.php` replace the function `show_pop_posts()` with this one

```
function show_pop_posts() {
    global $wpdb, $siteurl, $tableposts, $id;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("select postnumber, cntaccess from mostAccessed ORDER BY cntaccess DESC LIMIT 7");
    echo "<ul>";
    if ($results) {
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($result->postnumber).'">'.get_the_title($result->postnumber).'</a> ('.$result->cntaccess.')</li>';
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```